# I'm having trouble clicking a link automatically in Google chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have been working on this webpage.  There's a link I have to click automatically when a certain action is completed.  I tried this code

```
window.onload=function() {
    if(document.getElementById('link') !== null || document.getElementById('link') !== " ") {
        document.getElementById('link').click();
    }
};
```

It works on every browser even on internet explorer but not for Google chrome.  I don't know if Google chrome requires a different fxn.

Comment: So what's the error message?

Comment: There no error message. It works on all browsers except chrome.

Comment: Show us the html of the link you are trying to click

Comment: <a id='link' href='cotmsg.php'>click</a>";

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this and try

```
window.onload=function() {
    if(document.getElementById('link').length != 0) {
        document.getElementById('link').click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon at the end of the code, making it:

```
window.onload=function() {
    if(document.getElementById('link') !== null || document.getElementById('link') !== " ") {
        document.getElementById('link').click();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work for Google chrome.  Its like chrome requires a different fnx to click().

Comment: I just tested the .click() function on chrome using a very simple script clicking a link, it seems to work fine with .click() on Chrome. Try using to console to make sure that Chrome actually finds document.getElementById('link') and try running .click manually.

Comment: Just tried the code without the ; and got this error msg "object members.php?max=89 has no method click".  The members.php?max=89 is the href of the link.